# Error in model override in magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, shipping

I have override model for flat rate shipping rates. But its not reflecting

Please check below code for override issue in my module

Any issue in my code?

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate" type="Namespace\Module\Model\Carrier\Flatrate" />
</config>
```

**Flatrate.php**

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Namespace\Module\Model\Carrier;

use \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate\ItemPriceCalculator;
use \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier;
use \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface;
use \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;

/**
 * Flat rate shipping model
 */
class Flatrate extends \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = 'flatrate';

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_isFixed = true;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory
     */
    protected $_rateResultFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory
     */
    protected $_rateMethodFactory;

    /**
     * @var ItemPriceCalculator
     */
    private $itemPriceCalculator;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
     * @param ItemPriceCalculator $itemPriceCalculator
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate\ItemPriceCalculator $itemPriceCalculator,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        $this->itemPriceCalculator = $itemPriceCalculator;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @return Result|bool
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        $freeBoxes = $this->getFreeBoxesCount($request);
        $this->setFreeBoxes($freeBoxes);

        /** @var Result $result */
        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

        $shippingPrice = $this->getShippingPrice($request, $freeBoxes);

        if ($shippingPrice !== false) {
            $method = $this->createResultMethod($shippingPrice);
            $result->append($method);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @return int
     */
    private function getFreeBoxesCount(RateRequest $request)
    {
        $freeBoxes = 0;
        if ($request->getAllItems()) {
            foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual() || $item->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                    $freeBoxes += $this->getFreeBoxesCountFromChildren($item);
                } elseif ($item->getFreeShipping()) {
                    $freeBoxes += $item->getQty();
                }
            }
        }
        return $freeBoxes;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return ['flatrate' => $this->getConfigData('name')];
    }

    /**
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @param int $freeBoxes
     * @return bool|float
     */
    private function getShippingPrice(RateRequest $request, $freeBoxes)
    {
        $shippingPrice = false;

        $configPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');

        if ($this->getConfigData('type') === 'O') {
            // per order
            $shippingPrice = $this->itemPriceCalculator->getShippingPricePerOrder($request, $configPrice, $freeBoxes);
        } elseif ($this->getConfigData('type') === 'I') {
            // per item
            $shippingPrice = $this->itemPriceCalculator->getShippingPricePerItem($request, $configPrice, $freeBoxes);
        }

        $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($shippingPrice);

        if ($shippingPrice !== false && (
                $request->getFreeShipping() === true || $request->getPackageQty() == $freeBoxes
            )
        ) {
            $shippingPrice = '0.00';
        }
        return $shippingPrice;
    }

    /**
     * @param int|float $shippingPrice
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method
     */
    private function createResultMethod($shippingPrice)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
        $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

        $method->setCarrier('flatrate');
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod('flatrate');
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

        $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
        $method->setCost($shippingPrice);
        return $method;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $item
     * @return mixed
     */
    private function getFreeBoxesCountFromChildren($item)
    {
        $freeBoxes = 0;
        foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
            if ($child->getFreeShipping() && !$child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                $freeBoxes += $item->getQty() * $child->getQty();
            }
        }
        return $freeBoxes;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you checked after updated its working or not?

Comment: @Rakesh I updated the code still not working now core class also not applied

Comment: you haven't updated yet code, please add \ before Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate name in your flatrate.php file

Comment: @Rakesh Check updated question

Comment: I'm facing same issue. Have you found solution?

Answer (score 1):

All code are looks good, You can not call private method outside of class and in Flatrate.php all methods are private so only solution is you have to override hole Flatrate.php so it will not call core Flatrate.php

You can override like below :

**1. etc\di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
    <preference for="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate" type="Namespace\Module\Model\OfflineShipping\Carrier\Override\FlatrateOverride" />
</config>
```

**2. Namespace\Module\Model\OfflineShipping\Carrier\Override\FlatrateOverride.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Namespace\Module\Model\OfflineShipping\Carrier\Override;

use Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate\ItemPriceCalculator;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;

/**
 * Flat rate shipping model
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class FlatrateOverride extends AbstractCarrier implements CarrierInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = 'flatrate';

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_isFixed = true;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory
     */
    protected $_rateResultFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory
     */
    protected $_rateMethodFactory;

    /**
     * @var ItemPriceCalculator
     */
    private $itemPriceCalculator;

    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $quoteItemHelperSubscribePro;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
     * @param ItemPriceCalculator $itemPriceCalculator
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate\ItemPriceCalculator $itemPriceCalculator,
        \Swarming\SubscribePro\Helper\QuoteItem $quoteItemHelperSubscribePro,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        $this->itemPriceCalculator = $itemPriceCalculator;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->quoteItemHelperSubscribePro = $quoteItemHelperSubscribePro;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @return Result|bool
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        $freeBoxes = $this->getFreeBoxesCount($request);
        $this->setFreeBoxes($freeBoxes);

        /** @var Result $result */
        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

        $shippingPrice = $this->getShippingPrice($request, $freeBoxes);

        if ($shippingPrice !== false) {
            $method = $this->createResultMethod($shippingPrice);
            $result->append($method);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @return int
     */
    private function getFreeBoxesCount(RateRequest $request)
    {
        $freeBoxes = 0;
        if ($request->getAllItems()) {
            foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual() || $item->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                    $freeBoxes += $this->getFreeBoxesCountFromChildren($item);
                } elseif ($item->getFreeShipping()) {
                    $freeBoxes += $item->getQty();
                }
            }
        }
        return $freeBoxes;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return ['flatrate' => $this->getConfigData('name')];
    }

    /**
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @param int $freeBoxes
     * @return bool|float
     */
    private function getShippingPrice(RateRequest $request, $freeBoxes)
    {
        $shippingPrice = false;

        $configPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');
        if ($this->getConfigData('type') === 'O') {
            // per order
            $shippingPrice = $this->itemPriceCalculator->getShippingPricePerOrder($request, $configPrice, $freeBoxes);
        } elseif ($this->getConfigData('type') === 'I') {
            // per item
            $shippingPrice = $this->itemPriceCalculator->getShippingPricePerItem($request, $configPrice, $freeBoxes);
        }

        $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($shippingPrice);

        if ($shippingPrice !== false && $request->getPackageQty() == $freeBoxes) {
            $shippingPrice = '0.00';
        }      

        return $shippingPrice;
    }

    /**
     * @param int|float $shippingPrice
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method
     */
    private function createResultMethod($shippingPrice)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
        $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

        $method->setCarrier('flatrate');
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod('flatrate');
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

        $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
        $method->setCost($shippingPrice);
        return $method;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $item
     * @return mixed
     */
    private function getFreeBoxesCountFromChildren($item)
    {
        $freeBoxes = 0;
        foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
            if ($child->getFreeShipping() && !$child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                $freeBoxes += $item->getQty() * $child->getQty();
            }
        }
        return $freeBoxes;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It's not working

Answer (score 0):

Your Flatrate.php file class declaration line with below code have error of missing slash `\` before magento declaration file,

```
class Flatrate extends Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate
{ }
```

Replace with,

```
class Flatrate extends \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate
{ }
```

your **di.xml** file should be,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate" type="Namespace\Module\Model\Carrier\Flatrate" />
</config>
```

Comment: I updated the code still not working now core class also not applied